# Finding Maximum taking too much time in ILP, why?

Tags: integer, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, integer-programming

In short, we are now trying to change the IQP into the ILP. It took about 2 days with the old implementation to finish, now with linear tools -- it should speed up. Basically the problem is to maximize (with about 50 binary vars):

$$\sum_{g=1}^{5}sum_{p=1}^{10} ( S[p]x[g][p]-Tiredness[g][p]-Sleepness[g][p] )$$

**Update**

I think David is on the right track but when I try to maximize the expression with bonus -variables, they are zero every time, why? Below some code, scores could be like `S[1..10]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`.

```
int S[1..10] = ...; // Scores per player =s

dvar int x1[1..10] in 0..1;
dvar int x2[1..10] in 0..1;
dvar int x3[1..10] in 0..1;
dvar int x4[1..10] in 0..1;
dvar int x5[1..10] in 0..1;

dvar int b1[1..10] in 0..100;
dvar int b2[1..10] in 0..100;


//ERR: the values of b1 and b2 should be maximized...
// WHY not here so?

maximize 
sum(i in 1..10) 
(
S[i] *
    (
    (x1[i]+x2[i]+x3[i]+x4[i]+x5[i]) 
    - 1/10 * ( b1 +b2) 
    )
);

subject to 
{
    //We must play in 5 games.
    //It means that there are 5 players in each game.
    sum(i in 1..10) x1[i]==5;
    sum(i in 1..10) x2[i]==5;
    sum(i in 1..10) x3[i]==5;
    sum(i in 1..10) x4[i]==5;
    sum(i in 1..10) x5[i]==5;

    // IQP problem into ILP -problem

    forall (i in 1..10)
    {
        //ERROR HERE!
        //it returns zero for b1 and b2, they should be maximized... 
        //I am trying to use the tip by David here, see his answer.

        // EQ1: x2[i] * (x1[i]+x3[i])
        b1 <= 2*x2[i];
        b1 <= x1[i]+x3[i];

        // EQ2: x4[i] * (x3[i]+x5[i]+x1[i])
        b2 <= 3*x4[i];
        b2 <= x3[i]+x5[i]+x1[i];

    }

};
```

Comment: It's not surprising it's slow, because this isn't a linear programming problem (but an *integer* linear programming problem) and you've got 50 variables, not 20. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: So you need to assign the players to the games, right? You haven't restricted the number of players in the game in your ILP problem, is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions like

```
x1 * x2
```

are quadratic if x1, x2 are both variables.  You have a 50-variable integer quadratic programming problem.  Also, your objective function isn't concave so CPLEX is going to have an especially hard time.
   However, since you have all 0-1 variables, you can convert this into an linear problem by adding an additional variable, say *bonus* for the expression with positive coefficients and *penalty* for those with negative coefficients, putting them in the objective function instead of the quadratic terms and adding the following constraints

```
bonus <= x1
bonus <= x2
```

or in case of a negative coeficient

```
penalty >= x1 + x2 - 1
```

Since you are maximizing, cplex will force *bonus* or *penalty* to the correct values at optimal solutions.
The penalty and bonus variables should be declared to be non-negative

```
dvar float+ penalty;
dvar float+ bonus;
```

Do this for for all the quadratic expressions and your problem will become a linear integer problem and solve much faster.

Comment: @hhh: That's because this answer is slightly wrong. Because it has negative coefficient in your objective function, it is not a *bonus*, but a *penalty* that you seek to *minimize*. The constraints are changed as well, I suggest `penalty >= 0` and `penalty >= x1[y] + x3[y] - 2 + 2*x2[y]`.

Comment: @DavidNehme: ... but incorrectly. The bounds need to be adjusted for the penalty case. Imagine what happens when x2 is 0 (you need the other constraint go away in that case) or 1 (you want the opposite). For the bonus case, it works like this, for the penalty, it doesn't.

Comment: @jpalecek thanks again.  Now this should work.  In the penalty case, if either x1 or x2 are 0, then penalty can be zero, but if both are nonzero, then penalty must be at least 1 and the objective should push it to 1.  In the bonus case, bonus must be 0 unless both x1 and x2 are 1.  If they are both 1 the objective should push it to 1.

Comment: @hhh the variables should all have lower bounds of 0.  So implicitly there should be a penalty >= 0 also.  You get this by declaring dvar as a float+.

Comment: His optimization function is a linear function, so it's always concave (and convex).